# AutoSSH monitor echo port bind to specific IP

Tags: networking, ssh, linux-networking, port-forwarding, tcpip

I'm using autossh for create ssh tunnel. Everything good excep paramiter `-M` of autossh.

It cannot bind to specific IP to remote host. By default, it create `0.0.0.0:20000`.

I wanna bind to loopback IP: `127.1.6.134:20000`. Could I do that?

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.1.6.134:7681        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.1.6.134:9100        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `GatewayPorts yes` set somewhere in your ssh config. Try disabling that, or adding `-o GatewayPorts no` to the call to autossh. That will bind the local port forward to the loopback address - although that might be just 127.0.0.1. I'm not sure if it will also allow 127.1.6.134.

autossh implements the forwarding by adding arguments to the call to ssh, like this:

```
ssh -L 20000:remotehost:20000 -R 20000:localhost:20001
```

With `GatewayPorts no`, ssh binds the local forward to the loopback address, per the [ssh_config man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html).